# qemu: installating ubuntu through ISO gets stuck, shows "SVM" CPU bit warning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I am trying to install ubuntu in one of the qcow2 images I have created, using the below command

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -nographic -smp 8 -m 8G -cpu qemu64 -cdrom ubuntu-19.10-live-server-amd64.iso -boot d ubuntu-19.10-live-server-amd64.qcow2
```

First it spits out a warning, and then just hangs

```
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
SeaBIOS (version 1.13.0-1ubuntu1)


iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+BFF8C9F0+BFECC9F0 CA00



Booting from DVD/CD...

ISOLINUX 6.04 20190226 ETCD Copyright (C) 1994-2015 H. Peter Anvin et al
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code...
```

I have searched a lot and got a number of solutions and possible problems but none worked.

1) Have tried with Ubuntu 20 also, but same error.

2) VT-x not enabled.

It is enabled, `lscpu` shows

```
Virtualization:                  VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Flags: .. vmx ..
```

3) Try with `-cpu qemu64`. Did not work

4) use `qemu-system-i386` instead of `qemu-system-x86_64`. But that fails with a different error

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

5) I did find out that the "SVM" CPU bit corresponds to "AMD Secure Virtual Machine", which confused me since my CPU is Haswell.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the issue was.

While using nested virtualization, the option `-cpu host` works. This advises qemu to use the same cpu format as the host, which in our case is also a VM, and which mostly will be using the host CPU format too..

The above setting works,

unless; you are using nested virtualization over a virtualbox, and trying to run qemu on the VM. Then, to make this work, we have to skip `enable-kvm` and the `-cpu` option altogether. It does make the qemu VM run slow, but it works.

Comment: i get this error when i try to run qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -cdrom debian-10.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso -enable-kvm vm1.qcow2 even on a real laptop. when i tried to add -cpu host the message disappeared. what may that mean? (btw also i have some suspicion (from before this accident) that all my machine soft (with its bios) secretly runs in a spyware vm. )

Comment: as i understand from https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1722074 this does not mean nested virt actually runs, it means possibility to run it. seems my cpu does not have that feature to be able to run nested virt.